# Merge array with same value in same key php

Tags: php, arrays, woocommerce, foreach, merge

I have this code:

```
$order = wc_get_order( 988613 );

$product_array = array();
$daty = array();
$counter = 1;
foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_key => $item ){
    
    $daty_dostaw = $item->get_meta('Daty dostaw');
    $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
    
    $daty_dostaw_explode = explode(',',$daty_dostaw);
    
    
    $daty[$counter]['product_id'] = $product_id;
    
    
    foreach($daty_dostaw_explode as $key => $data){
        $daty[$counter]['data'][] = $data;
    }
    $counter++; 
}
```

When I print it it shows me this

```
    Array
    (
    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 988012
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 13-08-2022
                    [1] => 25-08-2022
                    [2] => 30-08-2022
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 988087
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 25-08-2022
                    [1] => 31-08-2022
                    [2] => 30-09-2022
                )

        )

    )
```

I want to combine an array that have the same dates to display like this:

```
Array
(   [1] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => array(988012, 988087)
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 25-08-2022
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 988012
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 13-08-2022
                    [1] => 30-08-2022
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 988087
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 31-08-2022
                    [1] => 30-09-2022
                )

        )

)
```

I want to merge the array those with the same dates. I don't know how to explain it exactly, above I showed what I would like to achieve. I have already written thousands of lines of code using foreach and have not been able to achieve this :(

Comment: This is a bit tricky, because you basically want to group the data by two separate criterions. When there's two entries on the same date, you want to group them by that date, but otherwise, you want to group them by the product id instead. So I guess you should start by counting how many entries there are per date.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to convert `product_id` into an array if there are multiple products with the same date. I would search for such matches, create the merges, remove the elements from the individual occurrence or even the individual occurrence if it gets emptied. An example would be this:

```
$cachedDates = []; //Here we will store the dates we have gone through so far
foreach ($product_array as $key => $product) {
    foreach ($product_array[$key]["data"] => $date) {
        if (!in_array($date, $cachedDates)) {
            //Creating a cache entry for this date
            $cachedDates[$date] = ["keys" => [], "values" => []];
        }
        //Adding the key and product to the date's cache
        $cachedDates[$date]["keys"][]= $key;
        $cachedDates[$date]["values"][]= $product["product_id"];
    }
}

//Adding the new items to $product_array and cleaning up items that become redundant
foreach ($cachedDates as $date => $entry) {
    //We only merge items that have a not-unique date
    if (count($entry["values"]) > 0) {
        //adding a new item with the correct values and the date
        $product_array[]= [
            "product_id" => $entry["values"],
            "data" => $date
        ];
        //Cleanup
        for ($index = 0; $index < count($entry["keys"]); $index++) {
            //We remove the date from the data entry after finding its index
            $removeIndex = array_search($date, $product_array[$entry["keys"][$index]]["data"]);
            unset($product_array[$entry["keys"][$index]]["data"][$removeIndex]);
            //If the data array is empty, then the whole product was already merged into some other item(s)
            if (!count($product_array[$entry["keys"][$index]]["data"])) {
                unset($product_array[$entry["keys"][$index]]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**The code above was untested, if you find issues with it and errors, then provide the appropriate PHP input instead of its print, even a json_encode result is good-enough**